# Regex - match 0 or 1 times

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var re = /^(post|merge|delete) (\/WcfDataService1\.svc\/)(.*) HTTP\/1.1$[\s\S]*?(^{.+\}$)/im
```

This is used to match various items in a batch request:

```
--batchitems
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST /WcfDataService1.svc/Orders(123) HTTP/1.1

{"OrderID":"x58"}
```

- First group: the type (POST/MERGE/DELETE)
- Second group: /WcfDataService1.svc/
- Third group: anything which appears after WcfDataService1.svc, in this instance: Orders(123)
- Fourth group: the JSON string

This works great! When I execute `re.match(str);`, I am returned an array as follows:

```
[
    'POST',
    '/WcfDataService1.svc/',
    'Orders(123)',
    '{"OrderID":"x58"}'
]
```

However, I want the JSON string to be optional in my regex, as it will not always be present; e.g.:

```
--batchitems
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

DELETE /WcfDataService1.svc/Orders(123) HTTP/1.1

// EOL here
```

But my regex fails here because it's trying to match the curly braces and it can't find them, so the entire regex fails.

How to I make `(^{.+\}$)` optional (to appear 0 or 1 times)? I tried `(^{.+\}$){0,1}` but does not work.

Any ideas?

See: https://regex101.com/r/pT3fG0/2 and https://regex101.com/r/nO8xZ7/1

Comment: Maybe a bit of a silly suggestion, but you can do the basic splitting with some simple string matching, like `var lines = input.split("\n")` and then apply the regular expression to each line and count the lines etc.

Comment: Have you tried `(^{.+\}$)?`?  Or maybe it would be `(^{.+\}$){?}`... I'm no regex expert.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 1**

make the json part optional using `?` , as follows:

```
^(post|merge|delete) (\/WcfDataService1\.svc\/)(.*) HTTP\/1.1$(?:[\s]*?(^{.+\}$))?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rO4sO6/2)

[image]

Comment: Hmm when I do that, it fails to match JSON string: https://regex101.com/r/nO8xZ7/2

Comment: @PruthviRaj You changed the engine from JS to PCRE? I'm not sure that is an appropriate solution?

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Can you explain what the addition does? Is that using a negative lookahead?

Comment: @keldar no, it isn't negative lookbehind, In `(?:[\s]*?(^{.+\}$))?` ,   `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group, it doesn't capture the text and then the `?` at end made it all optional

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option could be:

```
(^(post|merge|delete)\s(\/WcfDataService1\.svc\/)(.*)(HTTP\/1\.1)([\s]*)($|^{.*}))
```

This works as you are hoping. You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mI3tL2/1)

Comment: Thanks! That's quite a clean implementation.

Comment: No worries, I tried to keep it as close to yours as I could so it was easier to follow.